# Emu8086 bug or bad code?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

```
call _main
jmp $
_main:
push bp
mov bp, sp
sub sp, 0
mov ax, 20
mov [_t+0], al
mov ax, 30
mov [_t+1], al
mov ax, 40
mov [_t+2], al
mov ax, 90
mov [_t+3], al
xor ah, ah
; MOVE DATA TO REGISTER
xor ax, ax
mov al, [_t+2]
add sp, 0
pop bp                
ret         

data:
_t:
db 5, 5,5, 5
```

The code above this should be valid and should return decimal 40 right?
Emu8086 allows me to assign "_t+2" but does not allow me to return the value. It gives me decimal 52 in the return result.
This is not the first time ive had issues with Emu8086 like this. I have been writing a compiler and a lot of the stuff I test does not run correctly in the emulator.

If this is a bug can anyone suggest a better simulator. I just want to clarify if it is a bug and I haven't made a stupid mistake

Thanks

Comment: Anomaly in EMU8086. Put the label `_t` on the same line as the data and remove the colon. So on one line it should read `_t db 5, 5,5, 5`

Comment: dosbox + ordinary DOS era tools? As assembler you can even use modern era things, like nasm.